# Outlook 2007: Automatically mark a mail when printed

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, printing, exchange

I am looking for a solution for my Outlook 2007. I don’t know if it is possible, but what I need is, that each time I print a mail, it automatically get marked in some way, either by a flag or a category.

I’ve browsed through different menus, settings and rules in outlook and scouted google for a solution but with no result. Don’t know if it makes a difference, but my outlook is connected to a Exchange server 2010.

I would really appreciate if someone knew a solution to this.

Sincere
Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point there really isn't any functionality to handle this.  I know that a negative answer isn't what you were looking for but it just doesn't exist at this point.  It would be nice, especially so you know which emails you printed, but it doesn't exist.

At this point you will have to do it manually by flagging them.

Comment: Hi Daisetsu, thank you for your answer. It better to know that there ain't such a function then to search endless